# How to use merge statement to split one staging tables into two for loading from Staging to RealtionalDB?

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge, common-table-expression

I have following tables. I want to insert values into companyGroup and Comapany from test1 table. what would be better way CTE or Using Merge directly and how can i do that using tsql. Test1 is on database A and company and companygroup are on database B.

```
    create table test1
  (
  companyID int identity
  ,CompanyName Varchar(50)
  ,[Group] Varchar(5)
  )

  INSERT INTO (CompanyName, [Group]) values ('Unknown', '0')
  INSERT INTO (CompanyName, [Group]) values ('APPLE', 'IOS')
  INSERT INTO (CompanyName, [Group]) values ('Google', 'Android')
  INSERT INTO (CompanyName, [Group]) values ('Samsung', 'Android')
  INSERT INTO (CompanyName, [Group]) values ('Lg', 'IOS')

  create table CompanyGroup
  (
     Groupkey int identity (0,1) primary key
    ,GroupName varchar(5)  
  ) ;

  INSERT INTO (GroupName) VALUES ('Unknown')

  create table Company
  (
    compnayKey int identity (0,1) primary key
    ,CompanyName Varchar(50)
    ,companyGroupKey int References CompanyGroup(GroupKey)
  )

  INSERT INTO (CompanyName,companyGroupKey) VALUES ('Unknown',0)
```

when I insert the values into company how can i convert group to int ? Any ideas? What would be Best TSQL for this load.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
  INSERT INTO CompanyGroup(GroupName)
  SELECT [Group]
  FROM test1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                   FROM CompanyGroup 
                   WHERE GroupName = [Group]);

  MERGE Company AS target
    USING (SELECT t.CompanyName, g.Groupkey
            FROM test1 AS t
            LEFT JOIN CompanyGroup AS g ON t.[Group] = g.GroupName
        ) AS source
    ON (target.CompanyName = source.CompanyName 
        AND target.companyGroupKey = source.Groupkey)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CompanyName, companyGroupKey)
    VALUES (source.CompanyName, source.Groupkey);
```